# Objective C: How to reload a view controller's table view when tab is selected

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I need to reload the data in a view controller when it's tabbar is clicked.

I am using the UITabBarControllerDelegate method as below:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3) 
    {
        [(SomeViewController *)viewController getData];
    }
}
```

where 'getData' is an instance method in SomeViewController class. However when I run my app, I get the following error

```
2011-07-01 02:12:11.193 onethingaday[19169:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController getData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600d500'
```

Can anyone advise me how I can overcome this issue? I just need to trigger the 'getData' method when tabbarcontroller.selected index ==3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me from the error message you get, that you use a `UINavigationController` in your tab controller; in this case, you cannot send directly the `getData` message to it; you should first find out which view controller under the `UINavigationController` should receive that message. (This is not actually related to the tab bar `selectedIndex`)

I don't know how your UINavigationController is organized, but you could do:

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
     if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3) {

   //-- option 1: getData goes to the first view controller in the UINavigationController:
         [[(SomeViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)viewController topViewController] getData];

   //-- option 2: getData goes to the last view controller in the UINavigationController (the visible one):
         [[(SomeViewController*)[(UINavigationController*)viewController visibleViewController] getData];

     }
 }
```

If you give more details about the organization of your `UINavigationController` I can help further identifying the right option.

Anyway, as you can see from the casts, there is something that is not fully ok with your design. I would strongly suggest using a notification for that. I.e., your `SomeViewController` registers itself for a notification of a given type :

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                             selector:@selector(someSelector:) 
                             name:ShouldGetDataNotification 
                             object:nil];
```

and the tab bar controller sends the notification for your controller to react upon:

```
 - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
     if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3) {

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:ShouldGetDataNotification object:nil];
     }
  ....
}
```

Look at [this post](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NotificationsAcrossThreads).

Answer (score 1):

See the solution to [InterfaceBuilder - UIViewController subclass not recognized as subclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412083/interfacebuilder-uiviewcontroller-subclass-not-recognized-as-subclass)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 3) 
    {
        [[[(UINavigationController *)viewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2] getData];//2 for 3rd tabbar since 0,1,2



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the `-viewWillAppear` method in your `UITableViewController` subclass.  That should be called automatically when the `UITabBarController` switches to the view.  It should look something like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    [super viewWillAppear];
    [self getData];
}
```