# Persistent unrecognized selector error [Storyboards]

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, runtime-error

I have set up a million and one views with button's and functions. But for some reason I can't get this one to work - I've re-made it 3 times now ... I have no idea why it's not working...

From the error that I'm getting I understand it has something to do with the storyboard ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412083/interfacebuilder-uiviewcontroller-subclass-not-recognized-as-subclass), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015419/iphone-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)...) because in the error it says: `[UIViewController click_newsletter:]` not `[LinkedinActionViewController click_newsletter:]`.

The problem is, I deleted the old viewController and made a new one and nothing changed?

### Storyboard Class linking

[image]

In the story board - the class name is the same.

### Class Declaration

```
@interface LinkedinActionViewController : UINavigationController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    UIButton *our_page;
    UIButton *newsletter;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *our_page;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *newsletter;

- (IBAction)click_our_page:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)click_newsletter:(id)sender;


@end
```

### Opening the view

```
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
        LinkedinActionViewController *action_view = (LinkedinActionViewController*)[[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LinkedinActionViewController"] retain];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:action_view animated:YES];
```

### ERRROR!!!

[image]

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   click_newsletter:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d205a0'

I've hit my head on the wall with this for over a day - any help would be beneficial! :D THANKS!

Comment: It's possible that the storyboard file is not updated properly in the simulator. Delete the application and then try again.

Comment: yourViewController is getting released as i faced same error today

Comment: It certainly looks as if the `newsletter` button is connected to the wrong object type.  Does the `our_page` button work OK?

Comment: @PhillipMills - No neither of the buttons work.

Comment: @Prince - I doubt that's the case as I have Zombie Objects turned on (To my understanding that would catch that being the problem)

Comment: @HampusNilsson - I just wiped the simulator and tried again... It got an error that I have not run into before (easy fix) - but had the same problem as before.

Comment: @Prince - I disabled Zombe Objects with the same error showing up. Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, just had a friend take a look at this and we found the problem.

If you go to the `linkedinActionViewController.m` file.

Click on file inspector button in the right pane.

[image: File Inspector Tab]

Then **MAKE SURE THE CHECK BOX IS CHECKED!@!!!!**

[image]

May XCode die a slow and painful death!